# NLTK only search noun synsets

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Here is a function I'm writing to check for the existence of hyper and hyponyms from a list of nouns.

```
def check_hyper_hypo(wordlist):
    returnlist=[]
    for word in wordlist: #by definition a base word has a word above and below heirachy
        x = wn.synsets(word)
        for syn in x:    
            if not(((len(syn.hypernyms()))==0)or((len(syn.hyponyms()))==0)):
                returnlist.append(word)
                break
    return returnlist
```

How do i check the length of hyper/hyponyms only for the synsets which are nouns? 
E.g.

```
for syn in x:
    if ".n." in syn:
        #rest of code
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also try

```
wordnet.synsets(word, pos='n')
```

It will only return nouns, if you want verbs you should use `pos='v'`

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
for syn in x:
    if syn.pos == 'n':
        #rest of code
```

Comment: It should be `syn.pos() == 'n'` or `syn.pos() == wn.NOUN`. `pos' can be a function, at least for my case: I am using wordnet version 3.0,

Answer (score -1):

another approach using wordnet and list comprehension

```
print ([len(wn.morphy(tag,wn.NOUN)) for tag in tags])
```